# An unknown scope was requested in AWS cognito - Amazon

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

[After creating the user pool in AWS cognito **view Host UI** to test the functionality I'm getting this result, which is not expected , it should work like a normal login]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx5wM.png)

I've added **scope = Organization** or **scope = ALL_ACCOUNTS**

I'm expecting the success response with user profile json response.

Answer (score 0):

Should scope be an OpenId scope value in this case? Unless you have configured a custom scope, it may be expecting a value like `openid profile` or just `openid`. [Here is a reference that may help](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims) and also [a guide from the Cognito docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html).